# AspNetCore.WsFederation get signin-wsfed redirect to HTTP when original request is HTTPS

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, ws-federation

The context is an aspnetcore 2.1 website hosted in a Docker container on port HTTP, along with the use of an Nginx reverse proxy exposing HTTPS 443 only.

The website is accessed from the outside on HTTPS, it redirects to an STS website on HTTPS, which redirects to the /signin-wsfed on HTTPS.

However, the response **location** from the /signin-wsfed is HTTP.

Here is the request:

```
POST https://core-mydocker.####/signin-wsfed HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-application, application/xaml+xml, application/x-ms-xbap, */*
Referer: https://sts-mydocker.####/Pages/Email/Default.aspx?wtrealm=https%3a%2f%2fcore-mydocker.####%2f&wa=wsignin1.0&wreply=https%3a%2f%2fcore-mydocker.####%2fsignin-wsfed&wctx=#####
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,ja;q=0.2
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/7.0)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: core-mydocker.####
Content-Length: 10612
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

and the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.12.2
Date: Thu, 21 Feb 2019 09:39:34 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Location: http://core-mydocker.####/Authenticate
Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Correlation.WsFederation.######=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HTTPOnly; Securesignin-wsfed; httponly
Set-Cookie: FedAuth=#######=/; HTTPOnly; Secure; httponly
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://mydocker.####
```

HTTP being inacessible from the outside, this provokes an error.

How does the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation determine the response location, considering that every parameter in earlier requests (wtrealm, wreply, ...) are HTTPS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could find the solution to this problem, which is related to Forwarded Headers.

It happens that configuring Nginx as follows:

```
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

and then configuring ASPNET Core as follows:

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions 
    { ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto }
    );
```

is not enough. The resolution is provided in this post [proto headers not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43749236/net-core-x-forwarded-proto-not-working)

Happens that by default, the KnownNetworks collection only processes 127.0.0.1. In a Docker environment where each container is on a separate IP, that's bound to be incorrect and therefore Forwarded Headers would be ignored.

As suggested by the validated answer, changing the code to the below, fixed the problem:

```
var forwardingOptions = new ForwardedHeadersOptions()
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
};
forwardingOptions.KnownNetworks.Clear(); //its loopback by default
forwardingOptions.KnownProxies.Clear();
app.UseForwardedHeaders(forwardingOptions);
```