# How to set the redirect URI when using Microsoft sign-in in a .NET 5 application?

Tags: authentication, asp.net5

I have created a .NET 5 application with Microsoft sign-in based on [this explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp).

It is working fine when running locally. However, something is going wrong when running the application in Amazon EKS. This became clear to me after reading error message I saw in the browser and after reading the network traffic.

This is how this looks like.
[image]

What becomes clear is that there is something wrong with "redirect_uri" (containing http instead of https). This is really frustrating as my application is using https. I use https when opening the application in my browser. It is important to mention that this does not occur when running the application locally on my laptop. What I hope for is that there is a simple way to set the "redirect_uri" property that is used in my code. In this way, I can guarantee that the right redirect uri is used.

Here is the source code I would like to change:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var configSettings = new ConfigSettings();
    Configuration.Bind("ConfigSettings", configSettings);
    services.AddSingleton(configSettings);
    services.AddSingleton<IAuthResponseFactory, AuthResponseFactory>();

    services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

    services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    });
    services.AddRazorPages()
         .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

    services.AddHealthChecks();
    services.Configure<HealthCheckPublisherOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
        options.Predicate = (check) => check.Tags.Contains("ready");
    });
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health/ready", new HealthCheckOptions()
        {
            Predicate = (check) => check.Tags.Contains("ready")
        });

        endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health/live", new HealthCheckOptions());
    });
}
```

So how do I change my source in a way that I can set the redirect uri correctly?

Comment: Are you trying to redirect from a controller? Something like return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to enable header forwarding.

**Step 1:** configure the ForwardedHeadersOptions

```
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.RequireHeaderSymmetry = false;
    options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;

    // TODO : it's a bit unsafe to allow all Networks and Proxies...
    options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
    options.KnownProxies.Clear();
});
```

**Step 2:** UseForwardedHeaders in the public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) method

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders();
```

**Step 3:** Only use UseHttpsRedirection for production

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

    // Forward http to https (only needed for local development because the Azure Linux App Service already enforces https)
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
```

See [How to set redirect_uri protocol to HTTPS in Azure Web Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189883/how-to-set-redirect-uri-protocol-to-https-in-azure-web-apps) and [.net Core X Forwarded Proto not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43749236/net-core-x-forwarded-proto-not-working)