# "Issuer name does not match authority" error when using reverse proxy in front of SSL terminating load-balancer

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, apigee

I am trying to deploy our data API using APIgee proxy. The data API is using .NET Core 3.0 on an IIS server on AWS EC2 instance:

[image]

When I make a call to the data API using Apigee proxy I am getting this exception on the IIS server:

```
Category: IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler
EventId: 0
RequestId: 80003dde-0002-fe00-b63f-84710c7967bb
RequestPath: /v0.1/wells/dpr
SpanId: |74716527-4b0a0a0f46d32af3.
TraceId: 74716527-4b0a0a0f46d32af3
ParentId: 

Policy error while contacting the discovery endpoint https://example.com: Issuer name does not match authority: http://example.com

Exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: Policy error while contacting the discovery endpoint https://example.com: Issuer name does not match authority: http://example.com
   at IdentityModel.AspNetCore.OAuth2Introspection.PostConfigureOAuth2IntrospectionOptions.GetIntrospectionEndpointFromDiscoveryDocument(OAuth2IntrospectionOptions options)
   at IdentityModel.AspNetCore.OAuth2Introspection.PostConfigureOAuth2IntrospectionOptions.InitializeIntrospectionClient(OAuth2IntrospectionOptions options)
   at IdentityModel.AspNetCore.OAuth2Introspection.OAuth2IntrospectionHandler.LoadClaimsForToken(String token)
   at IdentityModel.AspNetCore.OAuth2Introspection.OAuth2IntrospectionHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
```

From what I can see, the issue here is that the Loab-balancer is performing the SSL termination and making a call to the IIS server using HTTP and not HTTPS that is why the `issuer name does not match`. I have tried adding `UseForwardedHeaders` line to our .NET Core API:

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseIdServer(this IApplicationBuilder app)
{
        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });
        app.UseIdentityServer();

        return app;
}
```

which is called here

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app
        .UseCORS()
        .UseCustomCookiePolicy(env)
        .UseIdServer()
        .UseRouting()
        .UseAuth()
        .UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
}
```

However, that did not fix the issue.

**Update 1**:
I have also tried configuring the ForwardedHeaders like that in my `startup.cs` as suggested on the [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-3.1#other-proxy-server-and-load-balancer-scenarios-1) without success:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ForwardedHeaders =
            ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
    });
...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseForwardedHeaders();
    ...
}
```

**Update 2**
I tried overriding the request schema to `https` in the `Configure` method in `Startup.cs` as suggested in [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-3.1#when-it-isnt-possible-to-add-forwarded-headers-and-all-requests-are-secure-1):

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.Use((context, next) =>
    {
        context.Request.Scheme = "https";
        return next();
    });
    ...
}
```

That has **resolved the issue**. However, I am wondering how I can properly configure the `X-Forwarded-*` headers in the middleware.

**Update 3**
Thanks to @Chen who pointed me to resource which stated that I can configure the ForwardedHeaders in the `Configure` method like so

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
...
    app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
    {
        ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
    });

...
}
```

Previously I tried the same but I used both `ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto`. For some reason, using just `ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto` resolved the issue.

Comment: Have you tried [registering ForwardedHeaders in the service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-3.1#other-proxy-server-and-load-balancer-scenarios-1)?

Comment: Thank you Chen for the comment. I have tried configuring the forwarded headers in the middleware. Please the 2 updates I added to the question.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43749236/net-core-x-forwarded-proto-not-working) are two ways it might be useful.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I ended up using `ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto`  line from the link (see Update3 in my question) which resolved the issue :)